# How is a vacuum formed and measured by this pneumatics attachment?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, air

Please excuse me if this question is misplaced and also for my narrow understanding of physics.

Firstly, I'm asking simply because the robot I've now been set to work with uses an air pneumatics system. By way of a small vacuum it can move about objects from point A to point B. This vacuum is somehow created from a small attachment that is connected to a steady supply of pressurised air.

This crude illustration is made on MS Paint shows how the vacuum is made. I'm still puzzled as to why the input of air doesn't simply flow out of **both** of the other openings.

[image: crude illustration]

**EDIT**

I can intuit that the volume of air from the exhaust is the sum of the input and the additional air taken from the vacuum but **what is the force of the vacuum and how is it measured?**

(Side note)

> Does the surrounding environment (atmospheric presure) have any impact on the vacuum?

Any response is much appreciated.

Comment: Hopefully someone with more knowledge can provide a better answer but I suspect it is to do with relative diameters of the pipes requires a drop in pressure at the vacuum tube to maintain the correct flow through the device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If this were true the mechanism I have would only show this internally. My mechanism has three openings of all the same size.

Comment: Are you sure it is a T-valve and not a 3-way [ball valve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_valve)?

Comment: My only certainty is that it looks like I have depicted it in my question above. I'm new to pneumatics and can make no presumtions. It does not look like the ball valve you've shown.

Comment: The vacuum is created by [Bernoulli's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_principle). The high velocity of the air passing though the horizontal tube lowers the pressure in the side branch. I have never used a pump of this sort that worked with an air stream, but I've many times used this sort of pump that worked using a water stream.

Comment: I doubt that your understanding of the mechanism may not be correct. The pneumatic operation of the robot doesn`t mean vacuum only. The pressurized air must be moving the parts by pushing the piston or pulling the piston when the pressure is reversed. Just as a hydraulic jack works

Comment: @Rams Double negative? Can you please clarify what you meant to say?

Comment: @JohnRennie If you're cetrain that's the answer please make it so.

Comment: You have a good description of the pump now in an answer. Can you clarify what you want to know about measurement of the vacuum? That's a broad subject, and doesn't really get interesting until vacuum pressures below what this sort of pump could achieve.

Comment: By measurement of the vacuum, I mean the amount of force behind the moving air. I'm looking for something like X Newtons/mm^2. This is so I can get an idea of the weight that this vacuum will be able to hold.

Comment: To *calculate* the pressure you'd need a lot more details about the internal structure. Probably it's better to seal the vacuum inlet with [some quick-n-dirty lifting harness](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/109486/44126) and just measure the weight you can support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fairly good schematic of an air-powered Venturi pomp:

[image: http://www.coval.fr/image/venturi-vacuum-pump-principle.jpg]

The geometry (alignment of nozzle and mixer) is crucial, it is inertia that directs the compressed air toward the mixer.

The difference between the pressure of the compressed air and the ambient pressure is of course important, as it is driving the flow. In turn, this flow is the cause of the suction that can generate vacuum — in your case, though you do not describe in which conditions it is used, the object seems simply to be moved by entrainment in the air flow.

Comment: This diagram has helped greatly in my understanding. Now, is there a formula where the strength of the vacuum is relative to the strength of the compressed air?

Comment: No, there is no general formula, you'd need to solve the Navier-Stokes equations in the relevant geometry in order to get quantitative results.

Answer (score 2):

It is called a Venturi pump. Free expansion of compressed gas along the top leg results in a jet of gas with net momentum from input to exhaust.  Any gas entering from below that collides with this jet gets momentum directing it towards the exhaust.  It is a neat way of pulling a (not great) vacuum without needing electricity to run a pump.

Comment: How does this explain why the air does not flow out of both openings?

Comment: Robert - the trick is you need a high enough gas pressure and an inlet nozzle.  Again, the free expansion of the high pressure gas results in a large directed momentum. As an analogy, a water sprinkler can send jets (sprays) of water that don't just go every which way when leaving the nozzle.